# Select and wait until where clause is true

Tags: mysql, user-defined-functions

I want to make a mysql select like "select * from table where state=1" and it shouldt wait until the where condition results true. polling is not acceptable. i tried something with udf function and sockets but its more complex and so i want to ask if there is a solution thats already running

cheers

Comment: Sounds like observer pattern would be better here; the code that causes the update emits an event that gets picked up by any listener.

Comment: You're looking for a [trigger](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/triggers.html).

Comment: It is a 'transactional' database.  Your options are really triggers or another approach entirely as the two previous posts suggest.  Processing the bin log or something to respond in code would be a wonky solution.  Polling not acceptable, sounds like wrong tool for the job to me.